React-Router 6.23.0 - How to hide child path in the url after navigating to it
I have the following code for my routes in using react-router 6.23.0
const router = createBrowserRouter([
    {
        path: '/fruits',
        element: <Root />,
        errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
        loader: fruitloader,
        children: [
            {
                loader: bananaLoader,
                index: true,
                path: 'banana-services?',
                element: <BananaServices />
            },
            {
                loader: appleLoader,
                path: 'apple-services',
                element: <AppleServices />
            },
            {
                Loader: 'orangeLoader',
                path: 'orange-services'
                element: <OrangeServices />
            }
        ]
    }
]);

<AppContainerInnerContainer>
    <GlobalStyles />
    <Sidebar>
        <NavLink to="fruits/banana">Banana</NavLink>
        <NavLink to="fruits/apple">Apple</NavLink>
        <NavLink to="fruits/orange">Orange</NavLink>
    </Sidebar>
    <Detail>
        <Outlet />
    </Detail>
</AppContainerInnerContainer>


My requirement is that in the url path I don't want the child paths to show after navigating to the "page".
For example, when a user clicks on "Banana", instead of what react-router gives me, http://www.example.com/fruits/banana.
I want http://www.example.com/fruits but still be able view the banana page.  Sidebar should still be intact on the left side.  This is similar experience with apple and orange as well.   I only want /fruits to show despite the child they're click on.
Below is code related to how I want to use the routes and loaders.
export const BananaServices = () => {
    const BananaServices:any = useLoaderData()
  
    const { name, bananaTypes, content: { plaintext } } = BananaServices.item
  
    return (
        <>
            <h1>{name}</h1>
            <p>{plaintext}</p>
            <bananaTypesContainer>
                {
                    bananaTypes.map((bananaType:any) => (
                        <bananaTypes>
                            <h2>{bananaType.name}</h2>
                            {bananaType.map(({name, url}) => (
                                <li><Link to={{ pathname: `${url}` }} target="_blank">{name}</Link></li>
                            ))}
                        </bananaTypes>
                    ))
                }
            </bananaTypesContainer>
        </>
    );
};

Any help would be appreciated here!

Use something other than a BrowserRouter which uses the browser's URL to synchronize matched routes, maybe a MemoryRouter which doesn't use the URL. If you navigate away from "/fruits/banana" back to just "/fruits" then Root will be rendered. What is the actual use case though? You just need something from a navigation action to trigger one of those specific fruit loaders? I don't believe you'll be able to accomplish your goal using a router and configuration alone. What specifically do you need to run when accessing the specific fruits?

@DrewReese - I'm just really rendering something that's a "true" single-page app without the routes.  I'd like to keep the routes based on what's out of the box, just to future proof this thing.  I editted the question with what will be rendered when a navlink is clicked.  Let me know if I can clear things up for you.

Seems like you don't really need a router and routes then. I think using a router here just introduces unnecessary complexity. Just fetch the data you need according to the button/link/etc that is clicked and conditionally render the appropriate UI. If you are set on using a router then use a memory router so the actual URL (other than the one serving the app) is largely irrelevant.

If you don't need it to work with the router and can manage without the loaders being separate from the components, you could just capture the onClick and change the component rendered in the /fruits page. To do this,

don't use Navlink and just use Buttons instead (with the correct className to keep your styling consistent)
use the Button's onClick hook/handler to call setCurrentPage
Replace or modify <Root /> to have:

const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState<'banana' | 'apple' | 'orange' | ''>('')


The return value of Root should include the correct component, for example with :

   ... 
   const getFruitComponent = () => {
      switch (currentPage) {
         case 'apple' : return <AppleServices />
         case 'banana' : return <BananaServices />
         ...
         case '': return <FruitServicesIndex />
      }
   }

   return (
   ...
     {getFruitComponent()}
   ...
   )
}

Note that this approach probably isn't going to work well with the browser's navigation and back and forward buttons.
I would note that this is something of an anti-pattern, though. Making the browser URLs change correctly is one of the important ways in which SPAs have become better behaved compared to the days of AJAX everything.

How does this capture what the bananaLoader, appleLoader, and orangeLoader route loaders do?

It doesn't. OP would have to take over what the router is providing. If that is needed, then the MemoryRouter you've suggested would be the way to go.
